# Camera makes QQmlApplicationEngine load very slow

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I have a QML frontend (Qt 5.12 on Ubuntu 18.04) with a QML Camera element (QtMultimedia 5.12) to show a video live stream from a USB camera/ video grabber. The application works just fine without the Camera element. However, when adding the Camera, loading the QQmlApplicationEngine takes several minutes (~5 minutes on a really powerful workstation). Once the application started, everything works fine.

I implemented the very basic example and I searched for similar problems, but I can't find anything. I checked the GStreamer version, which is 1.0.

Same problem with the Camera examples no matter if I try the QML or QtWidget version.

This is what I'm doing in my QML file:

```
VideoOutput {
    source: camera
    anchors.fill: parent

    Camera {
        id: camera
    }
}
```

To overcome the problem temporarily, I tried to add a Loader (ApplicationWindow->StackLayout->...->Loader). I was hoping that all the elements except the video stream are available immediately. However, this just shows the ApplicationWindow without any content and I still need to wait until Camera is loaded.

```
Loader {
    id: loader 
    asynchronous: true
    anchors.fill: parent

    sourceComponent: Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Camera {
            id: camera
        }

        VideoOutput {
            source: camera
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really wondering why nothing is working as expected here.

Comment: What do you mean when say `QCamera`? The real `QCamera` somewhere in your project or do you mean QML `Camera` mistakenly called `QCamera`?

Comment: I mean the Camera QML Type. Corrected in the question.

Comment: I have all the same setup (Qt5.12 Linux release with Ubuntu 18.04), but I use a laptop integrated camera and there is no issue with loading.  I guess this is something to do with USB.  I would suggest a minimal APP with only the Camera and VideoOutput to rule out a QML issue.

Comment: Qt uses GStreamer to handle video input on Linux so it is probably a good to look at that project for issues related to USB cameras.